# How to flip particluar part of images with angled rectangle or any other angle shapes in open cv c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I need flip the particular part of image in opencv.I searched enough but i got only `cv::flip()` method to flipped the entire image, how can i flip certain part of image from a image by angled rect or any other angle shapes.

```
cv::Mat src=imread("memory.png");
cv::Mat dst;             
cv::flip(src, dst, 1);
```

Above code used to flip entire image.  but i need to flip certain part of image by angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean an axis aligned rectangular region, you need to define a ROI - Region-of-Interest.
You do this using [`cv::Range`s on the columns and rows](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a92a3e9e5911a2eb0cf0950a0a9670c76), or with the `cv::Rect` ctor/[operator](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a07413f2e3e63a12185b8b218c24c7270).

For example:

```
cv::Mat src=imread("memory.png");
auto roi = cv::Rect(10,10,50,50);// ROI origin is at (10,10) with size 50x50
cv::flip(src(roi), src(roi), 1); // Apply flip operation only inside ROI
```

Comment: sorry about not mentioning axis aligned rectangular region, i need to know all axis rectangle flipping, both align and not aligned rect(angled rect).

Answer (score 0):

You can use region or ROI in opencv.
All operation in your image can apply in regions.

This block of code can be helpful.

```
dst = src;
cv::Mat subImg = dst(cv::Range(0, 100), cv::Range(0, 100));
cv::flip(subImg , subImg , 1);
```

Note : I didn't ***test*** above code.